# Calling a formula on union of two ranges

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have some numbers in cells `A1:A10` and some more numbers in `B1:B7`.

I want to run a function that takes a range (like `IRR` or `SUM`) such that it will operate on the concatenation of those two ranges. Is there a way in Google Spreadsheets to make such a call?

For `SUM` there is the obvious workaround `SUM(A1:A10)+SUM(B1:B7)`, but this wouldn't do for a function like `IRR`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=IRR( SPLIT ( JOIN(",", A1:A10, B1:B7), ",") )`

Demo: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmyXqCqKRFBKdDZwUjdGSEk5ekp2VUxPb3ZjTllzZWc (to view the formula you have to make a copy)